# Save in-progress document changes as a new file

Tags: versions

Now that more and more document based applications do the modern "Save, Duplicate, Revert to" `Versions` thing instead of the traditional "Save, Save as, Revert". Having had 30 years becoming quite adept at the traditional workflow across many systems, I'm having trouble adapting.

In those applications using `Versions`, how do you save changes you've made to a document as a new file? For example, often I'll open a photo in Preview, crop it, resize it and then want to save it as a "cropped" version of the original file. Or I'll open a letter in Pages, change some details and decide I want to keep this version for a different recipient. Or open two videos in Quicktime Player, crop them both, concatenate one with the other and save the result as a new file.

It may be that that's simply not an option now, so I'm also interested in answers that describe a different workflow, that involves editing a file and somehow results in having the edits appear as a new file, leaving the original untouched. The same workflow for `Versions` and non-`Versions` applications would be great, or otherwise some good way of switching routines at the right time.

The related question of how to **discard** those changes in progress and revert to the last saved file has a useful answer, for now, [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/445849/202413). And I assume the answer to [this 10 year old question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/50585/202413) is sarcastic, awaiting something a bit more sensible.

Comment: Some advice on how to improve the question and avoid down votes next time would be appreciated. I seem to burn a lot of cred asking questions and feel I might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For your Preview scenario, I would open up the Photo, select `File > Duplicate`, give it a new file name, and then do the crop, resize and save.

If you do the crop and resize and only then realize that you wanted to save it under a new name, then you can hit `File > Duplicate` at that point to save it under a new name. Go back to the original window and select `File > Revert To > Last Opened`.

Comment: That's pretty nice, particularly the second paragraph. Seems to work smoothly in a few examples I tried. "Duplicate" even gets the old ⇧⌘S save as shortcut, so it's really just ⇧⌘S, ⌘S, ⌘W, click "revert changes". Still feel like all this hoop jumping is some how "wrong", but working is better than wrong.